# Raspberry pi 3 B+ wlan0 not found

Tags: raspbian-buster, raspberry-pi-os-buster

recently i bought a raspberry pi 3 B+ but i can't connect to the internet through the wifi. I already read lots o similar problem on the internet but any of the suggested solutions worked form me. Since I'm very new to the world of raspberry I'd like to know what am I missing.

the problem is that when I boot my raspberry i got "wireless interface not found".

- If I run "`ifconfig`" or "`ifconfig -a`" I only got eth0 and lo, no wlan0
- If I run "`sudo iwlist wlan0 scan`" I got "wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning."

If I run `cat /etc/os-release` this is what I got

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Wpa_supplicant file configuration

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=IT

network={
 ssid="networkname"
 psk="password"
}
```

If I run "`sudo raspi-config`" under "localisation options" if I press "Wlan Country" I got this error "no wireless interface found" and then "There was an error running option L4 WLAN Country "

Any ideas? I don't know what to do, thanks

Comment: Have tried to follow the official documentation? https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md. Did you configure the wpa_supplicant file?

Comment: If you have access to a graphical Desktop -> https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/desktop.md

Comment: And here is a method to install wireless from the boot folder (headless). https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/headless.md

Comment: Yes I followed the official documentation and already configured my wpa_supplicant file. I edited the question with the wpa @PeterPaulKiefer

Comment: On the graphical desktop when I open the tab "localisation" the "Wi-fi country" is disabled

Comment: I would not mix the three configuration methods. Do you use a fresh Raspian installation or did you already configure some other things? You could try `journalctl -u networking` and  `journalctl -u wpa_supplicant.service` to access the logs. Perhaps you find something usefull (error reports). `systemctl status wpa_supplicant` could also provide usefull informaton.  Ahh one thing:  "networkname"  and "password" are not really values in the wpa_supplicant file they are just replacements for your real ones you want to hide, right?

Comment: The raspi is configured for a router/access point used in Italy. If your router is configured for another country, it might use other frequencies (only in the 5 GHz band) and the connection could not be established. SSID (networkname) and password should match with the Access point or WLAN router configuration (no typos)

Comment: Yep I put network and password just to hide my real ones.
I tried what you suggested and I got no errors. Wpa is active and running. And I'm in italy and I'will use my raspberry here @PeterPaulKiefer

Comment: The configuration for Italy affects you only, if your WLAN router or access point is configured for another country and can use the 5GHz band. Then it does not matter where you are, it only matters where the router thinks it is. If the supplicant service comes up, I have no idea what went wrong. Perhaps the Raspi is too far away from the Access Point, so the signal strength is not high enough.  First you should find out whether the hardware is available. `iw list | less` should output at least one `phy0`.

Comment: I tried this and it show nothing

Comment: Then the kernel modules for the wifi driver are not working. Try `dmesg | grep brcm`. Perhaps it shows you some errors. Try also `lsmod | grep brcm` to if the kernel modules are installed.

Comment: even these commands show nothing. I really don't know what to do. I also tried to install an eralier version (jessie) but still doesn't work

Comment: What's the content of `/boot/config.txt` - could be it's disabling wifi in there ... also try `grep Model /proc/cpuinfo` - to see what model Pi you actually have

Comment: There was no attempt to load the modules. This seems to happen on weak hardware. I found two threads: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=171112 Look at the last comment.  And a referenced from the first thread: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1002526#p1002526 . Does not sound really good, sorry. Perhaps @Jaromanda X has more ideas. But use `grep -i Model /proc/cpuinfo` instead of `grep Model /proc/cpuinfo` to search case insensitive. The output would be something like `model name : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)`  with a lower case word "model".

Comment: Why would you use `-i` when `Model` will match `Model` @PeterPaulKiefer :p also, you can simply `cat /proc/device-tree/model`

Comment: @Jaromanda As I said on my Pi the output is lowercase model not Model. Without the -i my output is empty, and the OP has already enough empty output ;-).

Comment: thanks guys I'll try asap and let you know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try what you want, as long as you don't see the WiFi interface **wlan0** on an unmodified Raspberry Pi installation, nothing will work. It could be that your WiFi is simply broken. To verify this flash a fresh [Raspberry Pi OS lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/) and boot it. Then you must see the WiFi interface **wlan0**, e.g. with

```
rpi ~$ ip -br link
```

no matter if UP or DOWN. If you don't see it then it is very likely that you have a problem with your hardware. I see no way to repair it. Just purchase a USB/WiFi dongle and you can still use your RasPi. That dongles are not very expensive.